# Ingress separated between HTTP and HTTPS

Tags: kubernetes

I have a backend service that speaks both HTTP and HTTPS. I want to implement an ingress that proxies the inbound traffic to the appropriate back-end port by using the nginx-ingress controller. i.e. I want to proxy inbound traffic on port 80 to port 80 on the back-end and the same for port 443.

A single ingress definition can only forward to a single port, therefore I have tried two separate definitions that does not work either.

Is this possible?